# Update column value from one position to another position based on indexed

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Hi I want to update the columns of table from one position to another position. Suppose I have 100 rows in which I want to update the fields from position 50 - 90 with one number. Example: `category` with id 2 should be updated from starting row 50 to last row 90.

I tried below mysql query:

```
Update table set category = 2 limit 50, 40
```

This gives an error. Any other way please.

Comment: Tables do not have any inherent ordering, so it is indeterminate to refer to "row 50" or "row 90" without specifying sort criteria.

Comment: okey I have autoincrement field in ID. Can I update based on id. Like from id 50 to 90.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not use a range LIMIT in an UPDATE query but you can use table joins.

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE `table` `t1` 
INNER JOIN (SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `category`='2' LIMIT 50, 40) `t2` ON `t2`.`id`=`t1`.`id` 
SET [YOUR CUSTOM SET]
```

Note: If you have a specific order, you can specify that in the INNER JOIN SELECT query.

Comment: Not correct: one *can* use `LIMIT` in single-table updates—see [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html)—just one cannot specify an offset.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was talking about this specific case where you would need an offset, row count pair.

Answer (score -1):

Use for-loop with this query

```
update user
SET username=(select * from (select username FROM user WHERE id=6) A), second_field=(select * from (select second_field FROM user WHERE id=6) B)
WHERE id=5;
```

In your case :

```
update category 
    SET category_name=(select * from (select category_name FROM category WHERE id=50) A), category_value=(select * from (select category_value FROM category WHERE id=50) B)
    WHERE id=49;


update category 
    SET category_name=(select * from (select category_name FROM category WHERE id=51) A), category_value=(select * from (select category_value FROM category WHERE id=51) B)
    WHERE id=50;

    .
    .
    .

update category 
    SET category_name=(select * from (select category_name FROM category WHERE id=90) A), category_value=(select * from (select category_value FROM category WHERE id=90) B)
    WHERE id=89;
```

Comment: Can you please describe your query part by part. THank you.